# List and count subdirectories that have files with same name character on string

Tags: filenames

Picture this:

```
 |-Main_folder
 |- Folder1
    |- E_1
      |- E_1_A
        |- file_E_1_A_F_1
        |- file2_E_1_A_F_2
        |- file3_E_1_A_F_3
      |- E_1_B
        |- file1_E_1_B_F_1
        |- file2_E_1_B_F_2
        |- file3_E_1_B_F_3
    |- E_2
      |- E_2_A
        |- file_E_2_A_M_1
        |- file2_E_2_A_M_2
        |- file3_E_2_A_M_3
      |- E_2_B
        |- file1_E_2_B_M_1
        |- file2_E_2_B_M_2
        |- file3_E_2_B_M_3
    |- E_3
    |...
 |- Folder2
```

I have this structure of subdirectories with files with a specific name.
I need help determining which and how many subdirectories named "E_NUMBER" have files in their subdirectories with, for example, a character "F" in Unix or Python.

Any help will be welcomed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU utilities:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find Main_folder -name '*F*' -print0 |
  grep -zPo '.*/E_\d+(?=/.*F[^/]*$)' |
  sort -z |
  uniq -zc |
  tr '\0' '\n'
)
```

Note that files such as `Main_folder/Folder1/E_1/whatever/E_2/whatever/xFy` are counted against `E_2`, not `E_1`.

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
for dir ( Main_folder/**/E_<->(ND/) ) {
  files=( $dir/**/*F*(ND) )
  if (( $#files )) print -r "$#files *F* files below $dir"
}
```

Where the file  would be counted for both `E_1` and `E_2` in the example above.

Shortened using an anonymous function:

```
for dir (Main_folder/**/E_<->(ND/)) () {
  if (($#)) print -r "$# *F* files below $dir"
} $dir/**/*F*(ND)
```

Replace the `sort -z | uniq -zc` with `sort -zu` or the `print` command with `print -r $dir` if you only need the directory path and don't care about how many `F` files it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in Unix". Should a recent shell like `bash` be OK, try

```
readarray -t FN <<< $(find .)
for i in "${FN[@]}"
  do    if [[ "${i%/*}" =~ E_[[:digit:]] && "${i##*/}" =~ F ]]
          then  echo "${i%/*}"
        fi
      done | uniq -c

  3 ./E_1/E_1_A
  3 ./E_1/E_1_B
```

It reads the directory tree into an array so the `for` loop doesn't choke on file / directory names with, say, spaces (doesn't help for line feeds, though). If in a matching path ("E_NUMBER" translates to the regex `E_[[:digit:]]`) the respective file name contains an `F`, it `echo`es the path name to be counted by the `uniq` command. If the `find` output is not in sequence, you might want to shove in a `sort` before the `uniq`.

Comment: `bash` is from 1989 (zsh from 1990), they can hardly be considered "recent" any longer. `readarray` was introduced in 4.0 though (from 2009, not very recent but macos, a certified UNIX system still comes with an older version)

Comment: Note that `[[ "${i%/*}" =~ E_[[:digit:]]` matches on `FILE_2_X`, maybe you meant `=~ /E_[[:digit:]]+$` or `= */E+([[:digit:]])`?